# Why state cannot be changed inside another method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created a backend, to which I can call POST or GET requests to send/fetch a list name and description as below.

My script should work like:

1. Page loads, then my app fetches lists data and shows it in another component
2. I can create a new list
3. My script sends it to the backend and after successful creation, my component fetches lists data again and displays it in another component on the same screen.

To pass data to another component I want to set state (setLists) to have lists variable available to pass.
Unfortunately when I am adding
`.then((data) => setLists(data))` instead of `.then((data) => console.log(data))` in `getLists()` method when I do `console.log(lists)` at the bottom of `getLists()` function I see undefined. I want it to be updated.

Now my script shows data at the very beginning but using this line `.then((data) => console.log(data))` which gives me nothing to play with. Then I can correctly save new data and preview it in response, but my state can't update as I told above.

I am looking for any resolution to what I should do to make it work.

Any code review ideas will be appreciated.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";

function Form() {
    const [lists, setLists] = useState([]);
    const [listName, setListName] = useState("");
    const [listDescription, setListDescription] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        getLists()
    }, [])


    function getLists() {
        fetch('http://localhost:5000/lists', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => console.log(data))
        .catch((error) => console.log('error'))

        
    }

    function saveList(listName, listDescription) {
        fetch('http://localhost:5000/lists', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            name: listName,
            description: listDescription 
        }),
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then(data => {console.log(data)})
        .catch((error) => console.log('error'))

        getLists();
    }

    function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        saveList(listName, listDescription);
    }    

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Form</h1>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="list-name">List name</label>
                <input type="text" className="form-control" id="list-name" onChange={e => setListName(e.target.value)} value={listName} placeholder="Enter list name" required />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="list-description">List description</label>
                <input type="text" className="form-control" id="list-description" onChange={e => setListDescription(e.target.value)} value={listDescription} placeholder="Enter description" required />
            </div>
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success">Save</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Form;
```

Comment: Try changing `.then((data) => setLists(data))` back and adding another `useEffect` hook as  `useEffect(() => {console.log('LIST DATA : ', lists); }, [lists]);`

Comment: @emkarachchi unfortunately your resolution don't work. I've got LIST DATA :  length: 0.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is right, you can write this in `getLists`:

```js
.then((data) => setLists(data))
```

But if you write `console.log(lists)` at the end of `getLists`, it’s normal that `lists` is still undefined. This line is executed before the promise (`fetch`) is resolved.

What you can do is put `console.log(lists)` just before the `return`. It might be displayed a lot of time, but at least you should see that `lists` is updated.

Edit: also I think that in `saveList`, you want to call `getLists` after the lists are saved. So maybe you should put `getLists()` in the `then` block:

```js
fetch('http://localhost:5000/lists', {
  method: 'POST',
  ...
})
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data)
    getLists() // <-- here
  })
```

Comment: What do you mean by return? I have no return in my code.

Comment: @browinski yes you do: `return ( <div>...`

Comment: Thanks, I see. Now the problem is that my script returns in console two positions:
1. []
2. full array

As I see [] is from useState([]) but I do not know why